# SQLITE_ERROR: table has no column named errno: 1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR' }

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sqlite

I just added a new column in my table (USR_IMG), which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
  USR_ID TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  USR_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  USR_ORGANIZATION VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  USR_MAIL VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  USR_PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  USR_IMG VARCHAR(150) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(USR_ID)
);
```

When I add a new user with the following code:

```
    var salt = createSalt();

    db.run('INSERT INTO USERS (USR_NAME,USR_ORGANIZATION,USR_MAIL,USR_PASSWORD, USR_IMG) VALUES ($username, $org, $mail, $password, $img)', {
        $username : req.username,
        $password : salt + ":" + hashPassword(req.password, salt),
        $org : req.org,
        $mail : req.mail,
        $img: req.img
    }, function (result) {
        if (result == null) {
            res({
                status: "Done"
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log(result)
            log(result, "error");
            res({
                error: result
            });
        }
    });
}
```

It seems the new column added (USR_IMG) has not been added correctly because I am getting the following error:

> { Error: SQLITE_ERROR: table USERS has no column named USR_IMG errno:
>   1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR' }

Any idea?

Comment: try executing `PRAGMA table_info(USERS)` to view all columns of the table

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have `AUTO_INCREMENT` coded, the correct keyword is `AUTOINCREMENT`. However, in SQLite `AUTOINCREMENT` can only be used in a specific case. That is the column has to be defined with a type of `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` (NOT NULL/ UNIQUE are implicit, you can also only have one such column per table).

So `USR_ID TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,` should be (if you want `AUTOINCREMENT`, you probably don't need it, as explained below) :-

```
USR_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
```

(*more likely `USR_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,` i.e. without AUTOINCREMENT*).

However you would then get a syntax error due to the `PRIMARY KEY` being specifically as per `PRIMARY KEY(USR_ID)`. So your code should be either of the following (i.e. without `PRIMARY KEY(USR_ID)` and the comma that ends the previous line, as there is no continuation):-

```
CREATE TABLE USERSS (
  USR_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  USR_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  USR_ORGANIZATION VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  USR_MAIL VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  USR_PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  USR_IMG VARCHAR(150) NULL
);


CREATE TABLE USERSS (
  USR_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  USR_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  USR_ORGANIZATION VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  USR_MAIL VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  USR_PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  USR_IMG VARCHAR(150) NULL
);
```

- ***Note*** you cannot use `ALTER TABLE USERS ADD COLUMN USR_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (with or without `AUTOINCREMENT`) as per [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). So you would have to `DROP` the table and then `CREATE` it.

With SQLite coding `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (where ?? is the column name) makes that column an alias for the rowid which is a unique up to 64 bit integer, if you don't have `WITHOUT ROWID` coded for the table, in which case you can't code `AUTOINCREMENT`.

The first assigned rowid will be 1 (unless overidden), the next will likely be 2 then 3..... BUT monotonic increases are not guaranteed.

`AUTOINCREMENT` enforces that each new rowid (and thus the column which aliases it) will be greater than any existing rowid for that table, whilst without `AUTOINCREMENT`, unused (*potentially lower*) id's could be allocated (*only after the highest has been reached*). AUTOINCREMENT incurs overheads as the algorithm is more complex and a system table (sqlite_sequence) has to be updated as it stores the last inserted id (the higher of the last used and highest rowid is used as the basis for the next rowid).

You may wish to read [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html). Although this extract, the first sentence summarises :-

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are missing parenthesis  replace this code this will work

```
 db.run('INSERT INTO USERS (USR_NAME,USR_ORGANIZATION,USR_MAIL,USR_PASSWORD, USR_IMG) VALUES ($username, $org, $mail, $password, $img)'), {
```

Answer (score 0):

I was editing the scheme from a local file in my computer, when I should do it from an SQL client (SQuirreL, DBeaver, etc), that was the problem!